# define array element by reference in C

Tags: c, variables, structure, typed

I'm re-writing a function (it works, so I'm apparently eager to break it) that iterates through an 2-D array.  The function will read an INI file for the contents of a given key, and either store the value returned to a variable or store a default value to the variable (in my structure, the variable is defined by reference as *pStoreToRef).

Support for storing a default value in my 2-D array is proving difficult.  All data types must be accommodated.  How to do so?

The 2-D array is typed by a structure:

```
typedef struct s_defaults {
    char        *cKeyTitle;
    uint16_t    nItemNr;
    uint8_t     nVarType;
    int         *pDefaultValue;
    uint16_t    nVarLength;
    uint8_t     nVarFloatDecimals;
    char        *pFormatString;
    int         *pStoreToRef;
    int         nNextItem;  // set to -1 at end
} site_defaults_t;
```

Here's the initializer:

```
site_defaults_t site_defaults[] =
{
    {"AUTOTUN_TOTAL_CYCLES\0",          SD_AUTORUN_TOTAL_CYCLES,            VT_INTEGER, 192,                            5,  0,  "%i\0",     (int*)&aAutoRunControl.nTotalCycles,1},
    {"AUTORUN_TEST_INTERVAL\0",         SD_AUTORUN_TEST_INTERVAL,           VT_INTEGER, 60,                             5,  0,  "%i\0",     (int*)&aAutoRunControl.nTestIntervalSecs,2},
    {"AUTORUN_TEST_LEN_SECS\0",         SD_AUTORUN_TEST_LEN_SECS,           VT_INTEGER, 30,                             6,  0,  "%i\0",     (int*)&aAutoRunControl.nTestLengthSecs,3},
    {"AUTORUN_TEST_FAN_SPEED\0",        SD_AUTORUN_TEST_FAN_SPEED,          VT_INTEGER, 85,                             3,  0,  "%i\0",     (int*)&aAutoRunControl.nSpeed,4},
    {"AUTORUN_TEST_PLATE_VOLTS\0",      SD_AUTORUN_TEST_PLATE_VOLTS,        VT_FLOAT,   40,                             3,  1,  "%2.1f\0",  (int*)&aAutoRunControl.vPlate,5},
    {"AUTORUN_TEST_SAMPLES_PER_SEC\0",  SD_AUTORUN_TEST_SAMPLES_PER_SEC,    VT_INTEGER, 10,                             2,  0,  "%i\0",     (int*)&aAutoRunControl.nSamplesPerSecond,6},
    {"SEND_FILES_FREQUENCY\0",          SD_SEND_FILES_FREQUENCY,            VT_INTEGER, 10,                             6,  0,  "%i\0",     (int*)&oSystemInfo.nSendFilesFrequency,7},
    {"POWER_60_HZ\0",                   SD_POWER_60_HZ,                     VT_BOOLEAN, true,                           1,  0,  "%i\0",     (int*)&aSystemState.Power60Hz,8},
    {"UPLOAD_ON_BOOT\0",                SD_UPLOAD_ON_BOOT,                  VT_BOOLEAN, false,                          1,  0,  "%i\0",     (int*)&oSystemInfo.EnableSendFilesOnBoot,9},
    {"AUTORUN_SENDFILES\0",             SD_AUTORUN_SENDFILES,               VT_BOOLEAN, true,                           1,  0,  "%i\0",     (int*)&aAutoRunControl.sendFiles,10},
    {"PREAMP_TRIM\0",                   SD_PREAMP_TRIM,                     VT_FLOAT,   0,                              3,  1,  "%2.1f\0",  (int*)&aSystemState.nPreampTrim,11},
    {"AUTORUN_PCIL_CONVERSION_CONST\0", SD_AUTORUN_PCIL_CONVERSION_CONST,   VT_FLOAT,   0.07608,                        2,  8,  "%2.8f\0",  (int*)&aAutoRunControl.pcilMult,12},
    {"ENABLE_DVDT_BEEP\0",              SD_ENABLE_DVDT_BEEP,                VT_BOOLEAN, false,                          1,  0,  "%i\0",     (int*)&oSystemInfo.AllowDvDtBeep,13},
    {"AUTORUN_PCIL_CONVERSION_ADJUST\0",SD_AUTORUN_PCIL_CONVERSION_ADJUST,  VT_FLOAT,   0.02,                           2,  8,  "%2.8f\0",  (int*)&aAutoRunControl.pcilMultAdjust,14},
    {"AUTORUN_DEMO_DURATION\0",         SD_AUTORUN_DEMO_DURATION,           VT_INTEGER, 30,                             5,  0,  "%i\0",     (int*)&aAutoRunControl.nDemoDuration,-1},
};
```

The new field, int *pDefaultValue; is proving problematic.  My theory was to store a reference to the value, and in this manner the stored pDefaultValue can be any type. That should work if the default value to store could be referenced to an address, but in this case?

Any ideas as to a work-around?

Comment: `\0"` - why would place two zero bytes on the of a string? Note that your string literals are not modifiable - I would consider `const char * cKeyTitle` and `const char *pFormatString` etc. I don't understand your question. Just `int value = 5;  site_defaults_t site_defaults[] = { .... &value ... }`

Comment: Instead of an int*  use a VARIANT.

Comment: String literals such as `"AUTOTUN_TOTAL_CYCLES"` implicitly include a null terminator.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your best choice is to have two members in this structure instead of just `pDefaultValue`. The first one is the string form of the default value, say, `pDefaultValueStr`. The other is `pDefaultValue`, which should be declared `void *` and to which the default value is stored in its internal form: the one that would be cast when the getter function needs to get one.

You would then execute an initializer population function early in the program execution that populates `pDefaultValue` given the content of `pDefaultValueStr` and `switch` upon `nVarType`.

The initializer, `site_defaults`, would have a null pointer given to each element's `pDefaultValue` and would be replaced by a usable, freeable, value by the initializer population function or it would "die" if the value cannot be converted from a string to its internal representation.

This initializer population function has utility also if the site defaults have to change given some input (string of course) from a user.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and not so great approach is to union it:

```
typedef struct s_defaults {
    uint8_t     nVarType;
    union some_union_name_in_case_you_dont_have_c11 {
        float f;
        int i;
        bool b;
    } pDefaultValue;
};

struct s_defaults site_defaults[] = {
      { VT_INTEGER, { .i = 192 }, },
      { VT_FLOAT, { .f = 1.92 }, },
      { VT_BOOL, { .b = true }, },
};
```

This results in many pages long switch-like statements to handle each type.

A way better way would be to use a function pointers and proper interface overloading.

```
struct s_default_vtable {
     void (*assign)(void *to, const void *value, void *cookie);
     void (*print)(const void *value, const char *fmt, void *cookie);
};


void assign_float(void *to, const void *value, void *cookie) {
    *(float*)to = *(const float*)value;
}
void print_float(const void *value, const char *fmt, void *cookie) {
   printf(fmt, *(const float*)value);
}

const struct s_default_vtable s_default_vtable_float = {
   .assign = assign_float,
   .print = print_float,
};
// similar for int and bool types

typedef struct s_defaults {
    const struct s_default_vtable *v; // vtable pointer
    void *cookie; // user context to pass to vtable functions
    const void *pDefaultValue;
    const char *pFormatString; // as this is tied to the type,
                               // I think it should be moved into vtable
                               // or just hardcoded into print function
    void *pStoreToRef;
} site_defaults_t;
```

Note that you can still use pages long switch statements by comparing the vtable pointer. Then you can use for example like:

```
// example for float type
float number_to_store_result_to;
const float float_default_value = 50.0;
struct s_defaults defaults = {
    .v = &s_default_vtable_float ,
    .cookie = 0,
    .default_value = &float_default_value.
    .pFormatString = "%f",
    .pStoreToRef = &number,
};

// assign default value to pStoreToReg
// no need for switch, no need for anything
defaults.v->assign(defaults.pStoreToReg, defaults.default_value, defaults.cookie);
```

Notes:

- String literals include zero terminating character. There is no need for `\0"` (unless you really mean to have two zero characters on the end of the string).
- The members:

  ```
  uint16_t    nVarLength;
  uint8_t     nVarFloatDecimals;
  char        *pFormatString;
  ```

rigth now duplicate information in your structure. You need only the format specifier for the type, for example for float you need `f`. The `%<this>.<this>` can be build dynamically with a small static buffer.

```
void print_float(int nVarLength, int nVarFloatDecimals, const char *pFormatString, float *value) {
        char buf[100];
        snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%%%d.%d%s", nVarLength, nVarFloatDecimals, pFormatString);
        printf(buf, *(float*)value);
}
// call like:
print_float(2, 8, "f", 1.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

String literals such as `"AUTOTUN_TOTAL_CYCLES"` implicitly include a null terminator.  So  `"AUTOTUN_TOTAL_CYCLES\0"` is actually placing two NULL terminators, one implicit, the other explicit.  It's not necessary.

Additionally, because you are initializing the `struct` with an initializer, the `type` of the first member could be modified to:  `const char *cKeyTitle;`

Next, The code as is produces an error message to the effect of "unexpected type name "VT_INTEGER" (and similar for other type names) for the struct initializer `site_defaults_t site_defaults[]`

This is because a `C` `type` cannot be used as a value.  This would be similar to doing this:

```
struct {
    int int;
    float float;
    ...
```

Following is a reduced scale replica of your original code for the purpose of showing how you might be able to solve your problem replacing `void *` for creating a flexible type to using a union:

This is a bare bones example, but includes a `main` function just so you can build it and experiment to see how the `union` works...

```
typedef enum {
SD_AUTORUN_TOTAL_CYCLES,                
SD_AUTORUN_TEST_INTERVAL,           
SD_AUTORUN_TEST_LEN_SECS,               
SD_AUTORUN_TEST_FAN_SPEED,              
SD_AUTORUN_TEST_PLATE_VOLTS,            
SD_AUTORUN_TEST_SAMPLES_PER_SEC,        
SD_MAX //count of items in enum list
}TASK;

typedef enum {
    V_INTEGER,//replace VT_INTEGER in initializer
    V_FLOAT,
    V_BOOLEAN,
}TYPES;

typedef union {
    int iVar;
    float fVar;
    bool bVar
}U_TYPE;

typedef struct s_defaults {
    char        *cKeyTitle;
    uint16_t    nItemNr;
    uint8_t     nVarType;
    U_TYPE      uVar;//union of types
 } site_defaults_t;




site_defaults_t site_defaults[] =
{
    {"AUTOTUN_TOTAL_CYCLES",          SD_AUTORUN_TOTAL_CYCLES,            V_INTEGER, 2},
    {"AUTORUN_TEST_INTERVAL",         SD_AUTORUN_TEST_INTERVAL,           V_INTEGER, 8},
    {"AUTORUN_TEST_LEN_SECS",         SD_AUTORUN_TEST_LEN_SECS,           V_INTEGER, 20},
    {"AUTORUN_TEST_FAN_SPEED",        SD_AUTORUN_TEST_FAN_SPEED,          V_INTEGER, 0},
    {"AUTORUN_TEST_PLATE_VOLTS",      SD_AUTORUN_TEST_PLATE_VOLTS,        V_FLOAT,   123.56},
    {"AUTORUN_TEST_SAMPLES_PER_SEC",  SD_AUTORUN_TEST_SAMPLES_PER_SEC,    V_INTEGER, 15}

 };

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @MarkRichards - You are welcome!  But what do you mean _mangling_?  (i.e. if its a `const char *`, which in affect it is as a string literal, I am not sure how it can become mangled.

Comment: To avoid overruns.  It's just a habit.  Noted.

initializing void * with an expression of incompatible type double

results with the above method.  (where the default value in the array is a float).

Comment: Initializing `void *` in this case with anything but `\0` would be wrong.  But if you want the member to be flexible in handling multiple types, it either needs to be a `void *, or you can define a  `union` with the members each representing the types you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one of many possible solutions.  Since you're using VARIANTs to describe information, let's use VARIANT.

I've trimmed away other struct members for clarity since this is all about initializing  the VARIANT and in this case irrelevant.

First an augmented struct for this example:

```
typedef struct SiteMeta {
    char* name;
    VARIANT v;       
};
```

Define a function to initialize a VARIANT.

```
VARIANT VariantValInit(const VARTYPE vt, const void* value) {
    VARIANT v;
    VariantInit(&v);
    v.vt = vt;
    switch (vt) {
    case VT_I4:
        v.intVal = (int)value;
        break;
    case VT_BOOL:
        v.boolVal = (bool)value;
        break;
    default:
        // throw or something.
        break;
    }
    return v;
}
```

Of course the function above would require additional cases to support other types.

Now declare your defaults like so:

```
SiteMeta site_defaults[] =
{
    { "AUTOTUN_TOTAL_CYCLES", VariantValInit(VT_I4, (void*)192) },
    {"POWER_60_HZ", VariantValInit(VT_BOOL, (void*)true) }
};
```

Comment: A really cool approach!  What is the typedef of VARIANT?  (Assuming VARTYPES_T for VARTYPE).

Comment: Well...since you were stating **VT_INTEGER** I assumed (oops!) your platform is WIndows which comes for free - otherwise easy enough to lift or duplicate from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/ns-oaidl-variant).  If you lift the struct, which is a union, and the VT_* enum, then `VariantInit` would be a simple `memset` to 0 the struct.  If you're not on Windows @KamilCuk's answer may be a better route, it depends on how much freedom you have to add the required code.

Comment: RamblinRose Thank you.  I've created an enum for that, and my use of names suggested otherwise:

```typedef enum
{
 VT_INTEGER,
 VT_FLOAT,
 VT_STRING,
 VT_BOOLEAN,
 VT_MAX_ENTRIES
} VARTYPES_T;
```

Comment: VARIANT would be handy.  I'm using gcc.

Comment: @MarkRichards indeed.  Fairly simple to create your own struct (union) and enum which surely won't approach the elaborations of Microsoft's version.